# I am getting a 404 error page after deploying my react app on Github (help please)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

So I followed the steps on installing gh-pages and deploying my project onto github. However, my github page is giving me a 404 error and gave me this message:
"If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file".
I have been googling around and nothing comes up.
I even switch the branch to gh-pages, but the page comes out blank.

Here is my package.json file:

```
  {
  "name": "dessert-menu",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://aaronv-github.github.io/DessertMenu/",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "save": "^2.5.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```